# Sending Data to Server Using Multiple View Controllers in ObjectiveC

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode

My current program I've made allows the user to input text into a text box which sends data to a server when a submit button is pressed.

However, I have multiple View controllers each with their own input boxes for the user to input data into. Example: VC1 has an ID and password text box, VC2 has an age text box and VC3 has a nationality text box.

Is it possible to submit all data from every VC at once? Do I only use a single php file to do this?. I am quite confused with the concept so any help would be great !

my php code:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$database = "testdb";

mysql_connect('localhost', $username);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to find database");

$name = @$_GET["name"];
$message = @$_GET["message"];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', '$name', '$message')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));

mysql_close();

?>
```

and my obj c 
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kPostURL @"http://localhost/TESTCONNECT.php" //variable to use whenever
#define kName @"name"
#define kMessage @"message"



@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
IBOutlet UITextView *messageText;

NSURLConnection *postConnection;
}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}




-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name{

if(name !=nil && message !=nil){

NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];

[postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];

[postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: postString]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

postConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


}
}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{
[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text=nil;
nameText.text=nil;

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

How are your fields displayed? Are they all in a single form, or in multiple forms?

You could display all of the fields in a single form, then all data for the form will be submitted in the same $_POST by the submit button on the form to the action parameter in the form.

If the fields are held on the same page in different forms you could use javascript to collect all the data and submit it all at once.

If all of the fields are on different views/pages, a work around to be able to pass all of the data at once; would be to pass the $_POST data from one view to the next and put it in a hidden field, so that on the last step, you can submit all of the data at once.

Comment: Passing the data from one view to another and submitting it by just using the last view is not a bad idea. Thank you! I will give it a try!

Comment: Quick question, if I do it this way can I pass it straight to the last view? Or does it have to go through each one?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your parameters of URL exist at several MVC, as a "Login" handle，you should access php
file at once.
If you want use parameter,just creat a .h file, define global variables use "extern", then assign them at your multiple MVC, so you get your data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a dictionary in appdelegate and save field in dictionary with key in each view controller and in final view conroller you can submit your data to server from dictionary1> Create Dictionary in AppDelegate  As PostDataDictionary; 2> Now In your view Controller [PostdataDictionary setObject:@"" objctforkey:@""]; set Object like these for every view Controller Now in Final View Controller ASIFormDataRequest *request;
            request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]]];
            [request setDelegate:self];

```
        [request setPostValue:[appDelegate.PostDataDictionary objectForKey:@"FirstName"] forKey:@"fname"];
        [request setPostValue:[appDelegate.PostDataDictionary objectForKey:@"LastName"] forKey:@"lname"];

        [request addData:imagedata withFileName:@"file1.png" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
}
```